# Prometheus: find max RPS

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, grafana

Say I have two metrics in Prometheus, both counters:

Ok:

```
nginx_ingress_controller_requests{prometheus_from="$cluster", ingress="brand-safety-phoenix-service", status="200"}
```

Failure:

```
nginx_ingress_controller_requests{prometheus_from="$cluster", ingress="brand-safety-phoenix-service", status!="200"}
```

Total:

```
nginx_ingress_controller_requests{prometheus_from="$cluster", ingress="brand-safety-phoenix-service"}
```

My question is how to find on which `RPS` failures occurred as `promQL` query

I'm expecting the following response:

```
400
```

Means, that if pod receives > 400 RPS, `Failure` metric begin to happen

---

full query (after got answered)
[image]

```
sum((sum(rate(nginx_ingress_controller_requests{prometheus_from="$cluster", ingress="brand-safety-phoenix-service"}[$__rate_interval])) without (status))
  and
  (sum(rate(nginx_ingress_controller_requests{prometheus_from="$cluster", ingress="brand-safety-phoenix-service", status !="200"}[$__rate_interval])) without (status) > 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the following query:

```
rps_total and (rps_failure > 0)
```

The [`and` binary operation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) is used for matching right-hand time series to the left-hand series with the same set of labels. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching) for details on matching rules.

Let's substitute `rps_total` and `rps_failure` with the actual time series given matching rules mentioned above.

- The `rps_total` is substituted with `sum(nginx_ingress_controller_requests{prometheus_from="$cluster", ingress="brand-safety-phoenix-service"}) without (status)` . The `sum(...) without (status)` is needed in order to sum metrics across all the `status` labels grouped by the remaining labels.
- The `rps_failure` is substituted with `sum(nginx_ingress_controller_requests{prometheus_from="$cluster", ingress="brand-safety-phoenix-service", status!="200"}) without (status)`

Then the final PromQL query will look like:

```
(
  sum(nginx_ingress_controller_requests{prometheus_from="$cluster", ingress="brand-safety-phoenix-service"}) without (status)
  and
  (sum(nginx_ingress_controller_requests{prometheus_from="$cluster", ingress="brand-safety-phoenix-service", status!="200"}) without (status) > 0)
)
```

Comment: Thanks @valyala, I edited the question since there problem with the query because its showing also values when its shouldn't,

Comment: It looks lile you missed `status!="200"` filter at `rps_failure` part

Comment: oh right, thanks!